# How to stop this fancybox opening on load?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out why this jQuery code makes a fancybox image open on page load rather than waiting for the user to click on it. How do I have it open when it's clicked on? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/j14gf3sv/3/).

```
<a class="fancybox" id="single_image" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg" title="title" 
                  width="200">
  <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"  width="300"  alt=""></a>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#single_image").fancybox({
        onComplete: function () {
            $("#fancybox-img").wrap($("<a />", {
                href: this.href, //or your target link
                target: "_blank"
            }));
        }
    }).trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the .trigger("click");

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#single_image").fancybox({
        onComplete: function () {
            $("#fancybox-img").wrap($("<a />", {
                href: this.href, //or your target link
                target: "_blank"
            }));
        }
    })
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/j14gf3sv/4/

Comment: Any idea why this does not work with fancybox version 2.15   fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/8j3mrs9w/1/

Comment: There is no longer an onComplete event, i have changed it to "afterShow" event and added jquery and it works ;) http://jsfiddle.net/8j3mrs9w/15/